# How to lock a database user account after some unauthorized login attempts in a postgresql

Tags: postgresql, user-accounts, lockout

I want to know whether Postgres has a policy to lock a particular database user after several unauthorized login attempts.

Comment: No, nothing built-in (unless you externally authenticate e.g. using LDAP, PAM or [similar technologies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html))

Answer (score 1):

You can write it using pluggins:

See https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/e/e3/Hooks_in_postgresql.pdf

There is a hook named `ClientAuthentication_hook` it is called after the login is checked and before the answer is sended to the client. There you can do what you want.